# Periodic Job Scheduler not working on Oppo and Realme Android Device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

Simple job scheduler is working fine in android device. When i add setPeriodic , my job scheduler is not working on oppo and realme android device

var jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

jobScheduler.cancel(101)

var jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(101, ComponentName(this, MyJobService::class.java))

.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)

.setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)

.setPersisted(true)

.build()

Comment: Try using WorkManager with a periodic task. It's recommended than Job Scheduler. It's more simple as well.

Comment: its not working